# An exponential function in an integral problem

Tags: calculus

Calculate $f(1)$ where $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuos differentiable such that:
$$f(x)= \int_0^x \ f(t)dt +2 $$

Aplying the fundamental theorem of calculus (and the thing that if $f=f'$, then $f(x)=ae^{bx}$, I think that this need to be $2e$, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You got that $f'(x) = f(x)$, so $f(x) = ae^x$ (the constant factor in the exponent is $1$).

Now, what is $f(0)$? This tells you what $a$ is. Then you can find $f(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

From $f'= f$, you can actually conclude that $f(x) = ae^x$ for some value of $a$. Now, knowing also that $f(0) = 2$, you can conclude that $ae^0=a=2$, so yes, $f(1)=2e^2=2e$, you are correct.